# Crossword solver in PROLOG

Tags: prolog, crossword

The creole of Paradise Island has 14 words: "abandon", "abalone", "anagram", "boat", "boatman", "child", "connect", "elegant", "enhance", "island", "man", "sand", "sun", and "woman".

The Paradise Times have
published this crossword:

[image: The Paradise Times Crossword]

The crossword contains some of the 14 words but no other words.

**Write
a Prolog program** that starts from

```
word(X) :-
member(X,
[
[a,b,a,n,d,o,n], [a,b,a,l,o,n,e], [a,n,a,g,r,a,m],
[b,o,a,t], [b,o,a,t,m,a,n], [c,h,i,l,d],
[c,o,n,n,e,c,t], [e,l,e,g,a,n,t], [e,n,h,a,n,c,e],
[i,s,l,a,n,d], [m, a, n], [s,a,n,d],
[s,u,n], [w, o, m, a, n]
]).

solution(H1,H2,H3,V1,V2,V3) :-
```

and defines the predicate `solution` in such a way that

```
solution(H1,H2,H3,V1,V2,V3)
```

is true if and only if `H1`, `H2`, `H3`, `V1`, `V2`, and `V3` are valid words of Paradise
Island which form a valid crossword when written into the grid given above.
(For example, the second letter of `H1` should coincide with the second letter
of `V1`.)

Use the query

```
?- solution(H1,H2,H3,V1,V2,V3).
```

to solve the crossword. Find all solutions to the crossword.

Hint: You might want to start from a smaller crossword and a less rich
lexicon.

Comment: OMG, i'm trying to solve this very same question right now! I cannot believe it!

Answer (score 10):

Just look at the picture, words are written with letters, you have everything in the picture, translaste it in Prolog lines (my solution has 12 lines, 2 lines for one word).

[EDIT] As every body gives its own solution, here is mine :

```
solution(H1,H2,H3,V1,V2,V3) :-
    H1 = [_,A2,_,A4,_,A6,_],
    H2 = [_,B2,_,B4,_,B6,_],
    H3 = [_,C2,_,C4,_,C6,_],
    V1 = [_,A2,_,B2,_,C2,_],
    V2 = [_,A4,_,B4,_,C4,_],
    V3 = [_,A6,_,B6,_,C6,_],
    maplist(word, [H1,H2,H3,V1,V2,V3]).
```

PS I originally 
    wrote word(H1), 
    word(H2) ...

Comment: I haven't coded in Prolog for 15 years, can't even remember what it looks like, but I'd love to see your solution out of curiosity!

Comment: My solution is just for this crossword, it's not a general solution. I just translate what I see.

Comment: This is the same example i wrote today... However this is not exactly what @Jhonny Tim asked.

Answer (score 3):

Uniquely domain-selecting `select/2` does the trick:

```erlang
select([A|As],S):- select(A,S,S1),select(As,S1).
select([],_). 
words(X) :- X = [
    [a,b,a,n,d,o,n], [a,b,a,l,o,n,e], [a,n,a,g,r,a,m],
    [b,o,a,t],       [b,o,a,t,m,a,n], [c,h,i,l,d],
    [c,o,n,n,e,c,t], [e,l,e,g,a,n,t], [e,n,h,a,n,c,e],
    [i,s,l,a,n,d],   [m, a, n],       [s,a,n,d],
    [s,u,n],         [w, o, m, a, n]
    ].
solve(Crossword):- words(Words), 
    Crossword = [ [_,A2,_,A4,_,A6,_],
                  [_,B2,_,B4,_,B6,_],
                  [_,C2,_,C4,_,C6,_],
                  [_,A2,_,B2,_,C2,_],
                  [_,A4,_,B4,_,C4,_],
                  [_,A6,_,B6,_,C6,_] ],
    select(Crossword, Words).
solve:- solve(Crossword),
        maplist(writeln, Crossword), writeln(';'), fail 
     ;  writeln('No more solutions!').
```

Test:

```
7 ?- solve.
[a, b, a, n, d, o, n]
[e, l, e, g, a, n, t]
[e, n, h, a, n, c, e]
[a, b, a, l, o, n, e]
[a, n, a, g, r, a, m]
[c, o, n, n, e, c, t]
;
[a, b, a, l, o, n, e]
[a, n, a, g, r, a, m]
[c, o, n, n, e, c, t]
[a, b, a, n, d, o, n]
[e, l, e, g, a, n, t]
[e, n, h, a, n, c, e]
;
No more solutions!
```

This solution only allows for unique words to be used in the puzzle (no duplicates are allowed). This might or might not be what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Prolog program per se, but a solution using Constraint Logic Programming can be found in [Hakan Kjellerstrand's excellent blog on CP](http://www.hakank.org/eclipse/crossword2.ecl). It's in ECLiPSe, but easily adaptable to other Prolog systems with finite domain solvers. Using CLP instead of pure Prolog will make the search much faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
solution(H1, H2, H3, V1, V2, V3) :-
    crosswordize([H1,H2,H3], [V1,V2,V3]),
    maplist(word, [H1,H2,H3,V1,V2,V3]).

crosswordize([], [[_],[_],[_]]).
crosswordize([[_, X1, _, X2, _, X3, _]|Lines],
             [[_, X1|R1], [_, X2|R2], [_, X3|R3]]) :-
    crosswordize(Lines, [R1,R2,R3]).
```

The algorithm isn't hard to get:

- we build the grid through the `crosswordize/2` predicate call
- we tell prolog that every list is a word

The `crosswordize/2` predicate is going through the columns two cells at a time while building lines. If you don't get it you still can "hardcode" it as Will did, it works too!

Comment: are we allowed to use same word more than once in crosswords? I think, usually not.

Comment: Well the definition said the crossword is valid if and only if every list a valid paradise thingy word. Since it's an if and only if I do consider the member instead of select call to be valid!

Comment: btw with member/2 I don't have any solution with the same word repeated so one way or the other won't change that many things in this problem :p

Comment: this is a puzzle creator; your version is happy to create crosswords with repeated words, if the lexicon allows.

Comment: sure, and as I said it's valid when refering to the definition given... anyway, it's trivial to edit in order not to allow duplicates, it's just a matter of how you read the exercice...

Comment: yes, of course. The `select/2` in my answer though just won't select the duplicates in the first place. It's a nice little "paradigm" to use. :)

Answer (score 0):

The theory here is to check for the letters which correspond to themselves in vertical and horizontal words. This can be achieved by using placeholders in the `word` rule. Checkout this gist https://gist.github.com/ITPol/f8f5418d4f95015b3586 it gives an answer which claims has no repetitions. However, coming from SQL, I think to properly curb repetitions will require a solution along the lines of `V1 @< V2`; because just using a "not equals to" is just not sufficient enough. Pardon the multiple "[k]nots"; it's actually not that complicated. Pun intended (:

Comment: if we remove the selected item from the pool of available items, there automatically are no repetitions possible. As I show in my answer. (that's what `select/3` does).