# crossword puzzle with prolog

Tags: prolog, crossword

Currently I am doing a Prolog [tutorial](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse7).

There is an exercise to solve a crossword puzzle with 5 words.

My Problem is that `Prolog` stops unification for my solution at a very early point.

It looks like that:

[image]

And there is a small knowledge base given:

```
   word(astante,  a,s,t,a,n,t,e). 
   word(astoria,  a,s,t,o,r,i,a). 
   word(baratto,  b,a,r,a,t,t,o). 
   word(cobalto,  c,o,b,a,l,t,o). 
   word(pistola,  p,i,s,t,o,l,a). 
   word(statale,  s,t,a,t,a,l,e).
```

To solve that task I have a predicate `crossword/6`.

So I have thought that the predicate `crossword` must contain 6 words that are made of variables and at every field where two words cross I have set there the same variable.

```
crossword(word(H1, A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1),
          word(H2, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2),
          word(H3, A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3),
          word(V1, _1, B1, _2, B2, _3, B3, _4),
          word(V2, _5, D1, _6, D2, _7, D3, _8),
          word(V3, _9, F1, _10, F2, _11, F3 _12)).
```

In SWI-Prolog I have typed the following request:

```
?- crossword(H1, H2, H3, V1, V2, V3).
```

So I have asked for the solution of a crossword puzzle.

The result I get is like that:

```
H1 = word(_720, _722, _724, _726, _728, _730, _732, _734),
H2 = word(_738, _740, _742, _744, _746, _748, _750, _752),
H3 = word(_756, _758, _760, _762, _764, _766, _768, _770),
V1 = word(_774, _776, _724, _780, _742, _784, _760, _788),
V2 = word(_792, _794, _728, _798, _746, _802, _764, _806),
V3 = word(_810, _812, _732, _816, _750, _820, _768).
```

**Question**: Why does `Prolog` stop unification at such a early point ? And why doesn't it return any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Prolog: solving a crossword scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220573/learning-prolog-solving-a-crossword-scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code declares a simple fact: there is a `crossword/6` predicate whose arguments are `word/8` predicates, and some of the arguments of the `word/8` predicates are the same. In particular, since `crossword/6` is declared as a simple fact, there's no relationship between the `word/8` predicates in the `crossword/6` declaration and the knowledge base (just like the fact for "astoria" doesn't constrain the fact for "astante").

Instead, only the words themselves are simple facts:

```
word(astante,  a,s,t,a,n,t,e).
word(astoria,  a,s,t,o,r,i,a).
word(baratto,  b,a,r,a,t,t,o).
word(cobalto,  c,o,b,a,l,t,o).
word(pistola,  p,i,s,t,o,l,a).
word(statale,  s,t,a,t,a,l,e).
```

Because these are simple facts with no conditions, we can always prove that there is a `word/8` predicate whose first argument is `astante/0`, second argument is `a/0`, third argument is `s/0`, and so on.

What you want to say is that the six words form a valid solution if other things are true of those words:

```
crossword( H1, H2, H3, V1, V2, V3 ) :-
  <conditions for a successful crossword solution>.
```

Next, define the conditions for `crossword/6` so that a valid solution is one in which the variables unify with the first argument of `word/8` predicates if the third, fifth, and seventh arguments of those `word/8` arguments unify with each other in the right way.

For an (incomplete) example, I can say I have a valid cross-word solution if the second letter of H1 is the second letter of V1, and the sixth letter of H1 is the second letter of V3:

```
crossword( H1, H2, H3, V1, V2, V3 ) :-
  word( H1, _, TL, _, _, _, TR, _ ),
  word( V1, _, TL, _, _, _, _, _ ),
  word( V3, _, TR, _, _, _, _, _ ).
```

Here I'm using underscore `_` to avoid giving names to variables whose names don't matter. I'm also using `TL` and `TR` for "top left" and "top right" to make the reasoning easier on myself. Prolog sees that we can prove `crossword/6` if we can prove that there are `word/8` predicates whose arguments unify in a particular way, and searches for combinations of `word/8` predicates that do so. The "knowledge base" provides axioms for each possible proof.

Do you see how to complete the `crossword/6` definition now? Notice that you'll need to give some of the underscore variables (called "anonymous variables") names to complete the solution, and introduce additional `word/8` terms on the right-hand side of the turnstyle.